# get-vm - wasn't recognized as name of cmdlet

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, powershell-3.0

We are trying to write a powershell script to start/stop our vms, but the `get-vm` command isn't working.  The error message is

```
get-vm: the term 'get-vm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

The code looks like this:

```
$temp = Get-VM -Server usa..... | where-object {$_.State -eq 'Running'}
```

We installed the update for powershell to get version 3 and it's still not working but the error message changed a little to the one I have listed above.

I saw this link: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/07decd82-270e-4dd0-b8e8-789d693099dd/powershell-getvm-error?forum=winserverpowershell

But `hyperV` is installed now and shows up when I type:

```
Get-Module  -listavailable
```

At the start of my code I have:

```
if(!Get-Module -Name HyperV)){import-module Hyperv}
```

There's also this:

```
[system.net.dns]::GetHostEntry(ip)
```

works and so does Get-Host

We tried

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All
```

but it wasn't recognized as the name of a cmdlet, etc either.

I tried disabling UAC like this link pshyperv.codeplex.com/discussions/359174 but it didn't work. This link shows commands I used:  http://www.ehloworld.com/1026

When I typed:

```
Set-UACStatus -Computer usa...net -Enabled [$false]
```

it gave the error message that `Set-UACStatus wasn't recognized as the name of a cmdlet`, etc either.  It didn't recognize Get-UACStatus either.

I'm not sure if there's another thing I need to import to use Get-VM?

Comment: When I just made it import-module Hyperv, it recognizes Get-VM now, but it isn't working to do $temp = Get-VM -Name usa0xxx.  $temp is null.

Comment: I wonder if it could be that powershell doesn't have the administrative privileges that I do with using my AD login?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out.  I needed to run powershell as administrator and then the get-VM returned the list of VM's.  I found the answer at [MS Technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/it-IT/586083bc-d3c7-4d77-a98b-e62939552afd/getvm-doesnt-work?forum=virtualmachingmgrhyperv&prof=required).